# Accumulative sums and Standard Deviation with loops for in Python

Tags: python, finance, standard-deviation

I has tried solve this but I cannot. 
I'm trying determinate standard deviation in finance, I mean:

```
Pr = Prob are equal [0.3, 0.4, 0.3]
r = Return are equal [0.10 ,0.05, 0.30]
```

So, first I calculate my average

```
E(r) = 0.10*0.3 + 0.4*0.05 + 0.3*0.3 = 0.14
```

Second, calculate my variance:

```
Var = 0.3*(0.1-0.14)^2 + 0.4*(0.05-0.14)^2 + 0.3*(0.3 - 0.14)^2 = 0.0114
```

Third, my Standard Deviation is

```
Var^(1/2) = 0.10677078 rounded  to 0.10677
```

In Python, I has tried solve using basic arhitmetic but I cannot do. 
My code is:

```
import math
def dev_stan(prob, ret):
    Pro = 0
    Des_Stan = 0
    Var = 0

    for i in range(len(ret)):
         Pro += prob[i]*ret[i]
         Var += (ret[i] - Pro)**2*prob[i]  
         Des_Stan = (math.sqrt(Var))
    return Des_Stan, Var, Pro, ret, prob

x = [0.30,0.4,0.30] 
y = [0.10,0.05,0.30]
print(dev_stan(x,y))
```

This code result in : `0.0956556` but this is not the answer.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is trying to calculate the mean and variance and standard deviation as some sort of running total, all calculated simultaneously. You can't do that with those specific formulas that you are using here. As you showed by hand, you did the mean calculation first, and only after you got the full mean did you calculate the variance, and then only after getting the variance did you calculate the standard deviation. You can't just apply that variance formula to a piece of the mean and hope things work out right.

```
import math
def dev_stan(prob, ret):
    Pro = 0
    Des_Stan = 0
    Var = 0

    for i in range(len(ret)):
        Pro += prob[i]*ret[i]
    for i in range(len(ret)):
        Var += (ret[i] - Pro)**2*prob[i]  
    Des_Stan = (math.sqrt(Var))
return Des_Stan, Var, Pro, ret, prob
```

should work. Notice that the final `Des_Stan` has to be outside the for loop. If you want to compute a running estimate of the mean, variance and standard deviation, you will have to utilize different formulas.

Comment: That's not true. There are several algorithms for single-pass or online variance estimation. Your solution is rather naïve.

Comment: I said "you can't do that with these formulas". I.e. with the formulas the OP was using. I will edit my post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

For mathematical calculations in python Numpy is what you want.

```
import numpy as np

def dev_stan(x, y):
    mean = x.dot(y)
    var = np.sum(x * (y - mean) ** 2)    
    std = np.sqrt(var)
    return mean, var, std, x, y

x = np.array([0.30,0.4,0.30])
y = np.array([0.10,0.05,0.30])
print(dev_stan(x,y))
```